# Why do the residue map extend to a place rather than an embedding?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Does anyone know how to fill the details of [Lemma 2.3.4](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Field_Arithmetic/FNkMaZrvpvsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA27) from the book "Field Arithmetic" by M. D. Fried and M. Jarden. The statement of the lemma goes as follows:

Let $v$ be a discrete valuation of a field $E$, $h\in O_v[X]$ a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, $x$ a root of $h(X)\in\tilde{E}(x)$. Suppose the residue polynomial $\bar h(X)$ is separable. Then author claims that $v$ is unramified in $F$.

A part of the proof says that the residue map $O_v\to \bar E_v$ can be extended to a place $\varphi_i$ of $F$ with $\varphi_i(x)=a_i$. Here for each $i$ between $1$ and $r$ $a_i$ is a root of $h_i(X)$ in $(\bar E_v)_s$.

How can one show the claim above? The book says it follows from the previous result that I wrote in [A homomorphism that extends to a place or an embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709231/a-homomorphism-that-extends-to-a-place-or-an-embedding) but what is the reasoning that it do not extends to a embedding?